# Unable to see output from COUT despite flushing & disabling syncing with stdio

Tags: c++, windows, g++, command-line-interface, windows-11

I recently switched to Windows 11 and was in the process of migrating. I noticed something rather bizarre when setting up my C++ environment, and frankly have no clue as to what could be going awry.

I am on `Windows 11 10.0.22631 Build 22631`
programs are compiled with `g++ 13.2.0`, distributed by the MSYS2 project.

A simple "hello world" program using `std::cout` no longer prints to the terminal:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  std::cout << "hello world!" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

but using `printf` works:

```
#include <cstdio>
int main() {
  printf("hello world!");
  return 0;
}
```

I've also tried setting `sync_with_stdio(false)`, which only worked if I use `std::cerr` instead of `std::cout`.
Redirecting the output to file also didn't produce anything at all, but the same program transferred to my old machine would work out-of-the-box

Comment: Could you add more detail to your question, such as what editor you are using and like is path for system variables for compilers are also set correctly or not

Comment: also you could try and ake change like use std namespace; like does it reslves your issues or not

Comment: Start by running your executable in the msys64 terminal that you compiled your executable with. If that fails to work perhaps your antivirus is the problem. If it works then you may have a problem with your powershell. Perhaps the runtime for your compiler is not in one of the folders of the OS PATH environment variable. Or perhaps the wrong / incompatible version of the same runtime dlls are in the PATH.

Comment: @NeerajRoy `using namespace std;` will absolutely not resolve the issue.

Comment: @drescherjm Yep running under ucrt64 worked so definitely seems like a Powershell problem. Path variable looks correct to me "C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\" which is where the compiler is.

Comment: Maybe there are other versions of the MinGW runtime in other folders of your PATH before the `C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin`. It does not have to be MinGW it could be any application that uses MinGW runtime.

Comment: @drescherjm That's it! Just needed to hoist my ucrt64 variable up. Thank you so much!

Comment: For example a few weeks back someone had a non-msys install of Ruby (about 90% sure it was Ruby) in the path and it held mingw dlls for a different version. Much fun ensued.

Comment: Side note: Placing the MSYS stuff earlier in the path likely broke whatever other tool was giving you grief. The only good answer is to carefully curate what goes into the path.

Comment: @user4581301 haha I'm still trying to pinpoint the culprit. More fun I guess.

Comment: Chiming back in a bit late, but if you put the path back the way it was, you can use [listdlls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/listdlls) to find out what DLLs the program has loaded (but not the ones it may have loaded and subsequently unloaded. Use Process Monitor for that) and where it found them. Make a C++ program that loops forever open a command prompt and type `Listdlls.exe <test program name>.exe` and look for anything odd like the C++ library dlls being pulled from a folder that has nothing to do with the toolchain.

Comment: @user4581301 That's a very handy tool indeed! Unfortunately, I think my test programs would terminate prematurely because they were loading a wrong version of `libstdc++`, so Listdlls was not able to capture any running process. I did find out what was causing the problem though. Apparently Neovim on Windows also happens to be built with MSYS2 and includes with the distribution a copy of `libstdc++`. When I had the Neovim folder in my path before `C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin` it seems to be causing the issue.